# How to get geo coordinates on clicked location of map using Angular-Leaflet-directive?

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

How to get geo coordinates on clicked location using leaflet?
I try something like ..

```
  $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.geojsonClick', function (e) {
             alert("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
    });
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular-leaflet` wraps up the regular leaflet event in the second argument.
Alos, you just want `'click'` like normal leaflet but with the `'leafletDirectiveMap'` prefix.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcjb3sr4/1/)

---

```
 $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.click', function (e, wrap) {
         alert("Lat, Lon : " + wrap.leafletEvent.latlng.lat + ", " + wrap.leafletEvent.latlng.lng)
});
```

---

Comment: I tried but still not working. It returns error in console.
    
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Comment: Ah! figured it out. After inserting a `console.log(arguments)` in the event, it looks like the leaflet event with the geo info is in the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('MapController', function (leafletData) {
                  leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                       map.on('click', function(e) {
                         console.log("Latitude : " + e.latlng.lat + " Longitude :  "+ e.latlng.lng);
                    });
              });
```